# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘extractUrlBase’ of undefined at GLTFLoader.load

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, gltf

I’m working with this example from Potree, here’s the link: 
[1](http://potree.org/potree/examples/features_sorvilier.html)
I’m trying to add this new GLTF file called “DamagedHelmet.gltf” instead of the object file called “stanford_bunny_reduced.obj” from the original the example, but I’m getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘extractUrlBase’ of undefined
>   at GLTFLoader.load

The added the gltf file where the object file was and I also imported the GLTFLoader.js file where the OBJLoder.js. I’m not sure how to solve this bug.

Comment: This demo doesn't reproduce the problem, but only shows your (working) OBJ version - a demo reproducing the GLTF issue would be helpful. But most likely, you've used a version of GLTFLoader that does not match your version of three.js.

Comment: [Loaders from r85 are here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/r85/examples/js/loaders), in that version the glTF 2.0 loader was called GLTF2Loader instead of GLTFLoader.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Don McCurdy! I updated my Three.js files and it works now!